What is the most general form of the distributive law for $\cup$ and $\cap$?
The following forms of one of the distributive laws increase in generality as we move down the list:
\begin{align}
(A\cup B)\cap C &= (A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C)\\\\
&\,\Uparrow\\\\
(\bigcup_{a\in A}F_{a})\cap(\bigcup_{b\in B}G_{b}) &= \bigcup_{(a,b)\in A\times B}(F_{a}\cap G_{b})\\\\
&\,\Uparrow\\\\
\bigcap_{a\in A}(\bigcup_{b\in B}F_{a,b}) &= \bigcup_{f\in B^{A}}(\bigcap_{a\in A}F_{a,f(a)})\\\\
&\,\Uparrow\\\\
\bigcap_{a\in A}(\bigcup_{b\in B_{a}}F_{a,b}) &= \bigcup_{f\in\!\prod\limits_{a\in A}\!B_{a}}(\bigcap_{a\in A}F_{a,f(a)})
\end{align}
Is the fourth formula the most general form of the distributive law?
Here, Brian M. Scott proves that the third formula is equivalent (within $\mathsf{ZF}$) to the Axiom of Choice. The fourth formula is also equivalent to $\mathsf{AC}$, while the first does not require it.
Is there a general form of the distributive law strictly stronger than $\mathsf{AC}$? (i.e., implying $\mathsf{AC}$ within $\mathsf{ZF}$, but not the other way round)
This question came to be as I solved Exercises 3.11 (second formula) and 3.13 (third formula) in Section 3, Ch. 2 of Hrbacek & Jech's Introduction to Set Theory, 3rd Ed. I wondered if there were even more general forms of the distributive law, and I deduced and proved the fourth formula. Then I wondered if there was an even more general form, and how much Choice would be needed for the most general form.

You're expected to show some work of your own. Have you tried, for example, proving the second formula to see if the Axiom of Choice is needed?

@jjagmath Alright, fair enough. I've added some context.  Although you may want to consider giving people a chance before downvoting and voting to close the question.

When I hover my mouse over the downvote arrow it says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". It doesn't say "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful. Add comments and give it some time to see if it's fixed, otherwise, click here"

True, but you and I seem to disagree on action. The "Add comments and give it some time to see if it's fixed" part is something I take as an implicit good rule to implement a priori.

That's where you and the site policies disagree.

You decide whether the question does not show research effort, etc. Not the site. The action to take with the policies offered is yours. And I will stop here.

I'm not sure how you could get more general than the last form you listed: it describes the intersection of an arbitrary family of sets, each of which is a union of an arbitrary family of sets.

Also, what you're asking for is a pretty tall order: if the "general form" should imply AC over ZF but not be equivalent to it, then it cannot be provable from ZFC. Of course we could pick some inconsistent "distributive law" like $A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup C$. But if you additionally want it to be relatively consistent with ZFC, then you're asking for a principle which is about the basic set operations, is independent from ZFC, and implies AC over ZF. If such a principle were known, I'm sure there would be an active debate about whether it should be added as an axiom of set theory!

@AlexKruckman I see. Thank you. I hesitated to add the logic tag, but perhaps I should have. I had a sense that consistency would be an issue. If you'd like to gather your comments into an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

I'm not sure how you could get more general than the last form you listed: it describes the intersection of an arbitrary family of sets with arbitrary index set, each of which is a union of an arbitrary family of sets with arbitrary index set.
You asked

Is there a general form of the distributive law strictly stronger than ? (i.e., implying  within , but not the other way round)

Of course we could pick some nonsense "distributive law" like $A\cap (B\cup C) = (A\cap B)\cup C$. Asserting that this is true for all sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ is inconsistent with ZF, so it implies AC over ZF, but it is not implied by ZFC, unless ZFC is inconsistent.
But if you additionally require the "general form" to be consistent relative to ZF, then what you're asking for is a pretty tall order: a principle which is about the basic set operations, is independent from ZFC, and implies AC over ZF. If such a principle were known, I'm sure there would be an active debate about whether it should be added as an axiom of set theory!

There are more general versions of the third and fourth laws listed in the question — versions which work in ZF alone, without needing the axiom of choice:
$$\begin{align}\\
\bigcap_{a\in A}\,\,\bigcup_{b\in B}F_{a,b}\,\,\,\,&=\bigcup_{f\in (\mathscr P(B)-\{\emptyset\})^{A}}\,\,\bigcap_{a\in A}\,\bigcap_{b\in f(a)}F_{a,b}\;\;\;\;\;\;&(3)\\
\hspace{-7cm}\\\\
\bigcap_{a\in A}\,\,\bigcup_{b\in B_a}F_{a,b}\,\,\,\,&=\bigcup_{f\in\!\prod\limits_{a\in A}\!(\mathscr P(B_a)-\{\emptyset\})}\,\,\bigcap_{a\in A}\,\bigcap_{b\in f(a)}F_{a,b}\;\;\;\;\;\;&(4)
\end{align}\\$$
This still has the general form of a distributive law: the intersection of a union is equal to the union of an intersection. (I think you can replace the final intersection in each formula with a union, but that yields an undesirable extra intersection/union alternation.)
Of course, there are also dual forms, with the roles of union and intersection switched.

Silly question (possibly) but genuine: Since my third and fourth forms are $\mathsf{ZF}$-equivalent to $\mathsf{AC}$ and yours work in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone, in what sense precisely are yours more general?

They're more general because they still apply to all the old cases that the original formulas covered, but they also apply to additional situations that the original formulas don't apply to (namely, if the axiom of choice fails).

I see. Your formulas express the same, but do so avoiding having to use the Axiom of Choice. Nice.
